# numpy, how to generate a normally distributed set of integers

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

What is the best way to generate a normally distributed set of integers with `numpy`? I know I can get floats with something like this:

```
In [31]: import numpy as np

In [32]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [33]: plt.hist(np.random.normal(250, 1, 100))
Out[33]: 
(array([  2.,   5.,   9.,  10.,  19.,  21.,  13.,  10.,   6.,   5.]),
 array([ 247.52972483,  247.9913017 ,  248.45287858,  248.91445546,
         249.37603233,  249.83760921,  250.29918608,  250.76076296,
         251.22233984,  251.68391671,  252.14549359]),
 <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: Unless you really need high accuracy, I would just round the floating point numbers.

Comment: OK, so like this: `np.random.normal(250, 1, 100).round(0)`?

Comment: And if you need actual integers: `np.random.normal(250, 1, 100).round().astype(np.int)`. (0 is the default for `np.round`, btw.)

Comment: You could plot the integer distribution on top of that of the floating point numbers, and see if you're happy with it.

Comment: @Evert What would "high accuracy" even mean in this case? The normal distribution is continuous by definition.

Answer (score 9):

The [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is a good discrete approximation of the Normal distribution.  Namely,

```
Binomial(n, p) ~ Normal(n*p, sqrt(n*p*(1-p)))
```

So you could do

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt

bi = np.random.binomial(n=100, p=0.5, size=10000)
n = np.random.normal(100*0.5, sqrt(100*0.5*0.5), size=10000)

plt.hist(bi, bins=20, normed=True);
plt.hist(n, alpha=0.5, bins=20, normed=True);
plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I guess this made me realize that I am (at this point) not too concerned with the specifics of the distribution, but more interested in how to get a set of integers conforming to any distribution aside from the default (uniform) distribution offered by `numpy.random.randint(..)`

Comment: Does this not generate any samples below 30 and above 70?

Comment: Something that I observed while using this is that the relative standard deviation of the normal distribution must be less or equal to sqrt(1/mean) of the normal distribution, when going from normal distribution to binominal.

Answer (score 7):

Came across this quite a bit later, but if you want to generate an arbitrarily-distributed set of integers, use the inverse CDF (percentile) for the associated distribution from, for example, [`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#statistics-scipy-stats) and draw percentiles uniformly from it. Then just convert to integers and you're done:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Generate 10000 normal random integers with specified mean (loc) and std (scale).
draw = norm.ppf(np.random.random(10000), loc=0, scale=100).astype(int)
plt.hist(draw, bins=20)
```

[image]

The list of [continuous distributions in `scipy.stats` can be found here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/continuous.html#continuous-distributions-in-scipy-stats), and the list of [discrete distributions can be found here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/discrete.html#discrete-distributions-in-scipy-stats).

Granted for the above example you could just directly draw from the distribution that you want and convert to integers, but the nice thing about this approach (sampling percentiles uniformly from the CDF) is that it works for any distribution, even one that you can only define numerically from data!

Comment: Very nice - hidden gem!